# Syntax error? How to fix that, and does it even run when fixed?

Tags: python-3.x, function, syntax-error

Afternoon, I am getting a syntax error(where it says right here) I would appreciate any help, and any help would be appreciated!

The prompt for this code is that it must have three functions
one where it generates random numbers, and lets user decide how many random numbers.

second function that displays the average of the random numbers, how many random numbers were chosen and the sum of the numbers.

The main function should let the user enter the file they want to write into, and pass the file name as an argrument when you call the function that writes numbers into the file, also pass the file name as an argrument when you call the function that reads the numbers from the file

Any suggestions are appreciated!!

```
import random
import math
def main():
    myfile = str(input("Enter 'filename.txt' here"))
    with open(myfile, "w") as f:
        rand_gen(my_file)

    return f
    myfile.close

    displayNumbers()
def rand_gen(file_name):
    my_file = open(file_name, mode='w+')
    for count in range(int(input("How many random numbers" + \
                                 "should we use?")))    **RIGHT HERE**
    randomNumber = random.randint(1,500)
    myfile.write(str.line + '\n'))
    my_file.close()
def displayNumbers():
    myfile = open(f,"r")
    total = 0
    count = 0
    print("The numbers are:")
    for line in myfile:
        number = int(randomNumber)
        total += number
        count += 1
        print(number)

    average = total / count
    data = np.loadtxt(f)
    print("The count is ", count,)
    print("The sum is ", total,)
    print("The average is " format(average, '.2f'))
    myfile.close
main()
```

I made an edit to that part. now the program will not continue after this

```
def rand_gen(file_name):
    my_file = open(file_name, mode='w+')
    NumofNumbers= str(int(input("How many random numbers should we use?")))   
    line = randomNumber = random.randint(1,500)
    my_file.write(str(line)+'\n')
    my_file.close()
```

Comment: ok so I updated one part, but after that it just quits on me. It lets me get the file name, and how many numbers.

Comment: def rand_gen(file_name):
    my_file = open(file_name, mode='w+')
    NumofNumbers= str(int(input("How many random numbers should we use?")))   
    line = randomNumber = random.randint(1,500)
    my_file.write(str(line)+'\n')
    my_file.close()

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the ':'

```
for count in range(int(input("How many random numbers" + \
                             "should we use?"))): # <----- colon missing
```

You may also want to check out the logging I have in STEP3 of my code [here](https://github.com/ProsperousHeart/Personal-Projects/tree/master/Cisco-Live-2018) in order to find out if things are working and/or where you might be breaking your code.